# Pure JS to lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I have some different statements here that I would like you to tell me if they are equivalent:

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {

  var result, i, sport, y, contains, league;
  return function(sports, filterBy) {    
    if (angular.isUndefined(sports) || !filterBy) {
      return sports;
    }

    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
    result = [],
    contains = function(haystack, needle) {
      return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1;
    };

    for (i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) {
      sport = sports[i];
      if (contains(sport.name, filterBy)) {
        result.push(sport);
        continue;
      } else {
        for (y = 0; y < sport.leagues.length; y++) {
          league = sport.leagues[y];
          if (contains(league.name, filterBy)) {
            result.push(sport);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
});
```

**now with lodash:**

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {

  var result, i, sport, y, contains, league;
  return function(sports, filterBy) {    
    if (angular.isUndefined(sports) || !filterBy) {
      return sports;
    }

    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
    result = [],
    contains = function(haystack, needle) {
      return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1;
    };

  _.each(sports.length, function(sport) {
      if (contains(sport.name, filterBy)) {
        result.push(sport);
        continue;
      } else {
        _.each(sport.leagues.length, function(league) {
          if(contains(league.name, filterBy)) {
            result.push(sport);
            break;
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

just I am trying to get with the logic of lodash. I have that function in ALMOST pure JS, but once I tried to translate that to lodash, my app breaks down, so I would like to know where is the mistake ?

here I have [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXBOsSu1WOSiYMeKyTZz?p=preview) with the pure js function, in the library section you will see that I have `underscore` because I do not know why `lodash` did not load, so, all I am trying is: translate that function into a `lodash` function using `_.each` instead of `for loop`

Comment: Remove `.length` from the first argument in both cases

Comment: An `each` and a `push` to a new empty array is almost always a `map` - both in native JS and with lodash.

Comment: I did not get you @BenjaminGruenbaum, could you give a code example ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer http://plnkr.co/edit/3eemdNxpdKdJV5YNy9Lg?p=preview no underscore, reduced your whole filter method to ±8 lines.

Comment: great but getting an error: ```undefined is not a function``` and the issue is on ```return (sport.indexOf(filterBy) > -1) ||``` line @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: It was just missing a .name... http://plnkr.co/edit/3eemdNxpdKdJV5YNy9Lg?p=preview

Comment: hey @BenjaminGruenbaum see this new one, maybe you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415602/issue-with-custom-filter-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use "each" in this situation. Also in "each" you don't get "continue" or "break".  For me I would use "filter" to get a filtered result. So the code should look like this:

```
var result = sports.filter(function(sport){
  return (
      contains(sport.name, filterBy) 
    || (
      sport.leagues && sport.leagues.some(function(league) { 
        return contains(league.name, filterBy) 
      })
    )
  )
})
```

or for lodash/underscore

```
var result = _.filter(sports, function(sport) {
  return (
      contains(sport.name, filterBy) 
    || (
      sport.leagues && _.some(sport.leagues, function(league) { 
        return contains(league.name, filterBy);
      })
    )
  )
});
```

Comment: Your inner `.filter()` for `sport.leagues` should end with `.length`, because it always returns an Array, which is always truthy. And actually, `.some()` makes more sense than `.filter()` because it returns a boolean and breaks the iteration as soon as the condition is met.

Comment: Good catch.  I can fix this answer.

Comment: i'm looking at your plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/3eemdNxpdKdJV5YNy9Lg?p=preview, and I'm not seeing a problem.  Can you point to where the problem is?  Are you missing to scan the "sport" object in the "league" attribute?