# Issue with custom filter, what am I missing ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with a custom filter I am working on, I am struggling with this because I am using Angular 1.3.6 and I can not upgrade now, so I really need your help in this case.

[see this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lGwvlBG36KXph2HSV0q?p=preview)

if you type **1H** the filter returns all the leagues with those characters, which is awesome, but, if you type... let's say: **College**, the filter returns all the `sports` starting with **College** but the leagues of that sports disappears, my filter works great with the leagues, but if you try to find any of the sports, then his leagues disappears and I do not want that, I want that if you search through the sports, the filter must returns every sports with their leagues respectively.

I want to keep the same behavior when you search through leagues, that is awesome now, my issue is just with sports. See my code below

**filter.js**

```
  .filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(sports, filterBy) {
      if (!sports || !filterBy) {
        return sports;
      }

      filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
      return sports.filter(function(sport) {
        return (sport.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) > -1) || sport.leagues.some(function(league) {
            return league.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) > -1;
          });
      });
    };
  });
```

**sportsLeagues.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | myFilter:query)">

   <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>

     <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter: { name:query }">

       <div>{{league.name}} </div>

     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What if you remove the filter in the second ng-repeat? Is that the behaviour you are looking for? http://plnkr.co/edit/UQDZ0amamy0bP1UZo9xo?p=preview

Comment: something like that, but type **ncaa** in your Plnkr, it returns all the leagues  and sports including **ncaa** but is not removing the other leagues like **LIVE BETTING - NFL** and **LIVE BETTING - SOCCER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another filter for the leagues that returns all the leagues if their sport´s name contains the query otherwise filters it normally:

```
myApp.filter('leaguesFilter', function () {

  return function (leagues, filterBy) {

    if (!leagues || !filterBy) return leagues;

    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();

    if (leagues[0] && leagues[0].sport.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) > -1) return leagues;
    else return leagues.filter(function (league) {
      return league.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) > -1;
    });
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0vYKtBETxDx1tD3udO9Z?p=preview